# Prestashop 1.7 - handle a file uploading in a ModuleFrontController

Tags: prestashop

How to get file posted in form in ModuleFrontController? I've added a

```
<input type="file" name="fileUpload"/>
```

in form which hits a Controller. Normally values are get by

```
Tools::getValue(...)
```

like in Prestashop 1.7 documentation

[Prestashop Front Controllers doc](https://devdocs.prestashop.com/1.7/modules/concepts/controllers/front-controllers/)

but

```
$file = Tools::getValue('fileUpload')
```

returns false. How to reference to file which was posted in form and eventually save it in given path?

Comment: You should use $_FILES variable. 
For eg. $_FILES['fileUpload']['name']

Comment: I've tried this, it returns null. Tools::getValue('fileUpload') returns false, thats some progress :)

Comment: Did you add enctype='multipart/form-data' in the form?

Comment: Actually I forgot, but adding it changes nothing. ModuleFrontController has method display() maybe it requires additional perameter?